# How secure is using a Yubikey to unlock a MacBook Pro with Filevault?

Tags: yubikey, filevault

I just got a MacBook and am planning on using it with Filevault and a Firmware password. How secure would using a new Yubikey be while using it to login [using the standard method](https://www.yubico.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Yubico_YubiKeyMacOSXLogin_en.pdf) if the computer gets stolen?

Would the Filevault key encrypted key be encrypted with the Yubikey or something?

Comment: I'm finding this an odd question. The document you linked doesn't even mention FileVault. I think you are assuming that the YubiKey can be used with FileVault. I'm not sure it can. FileVault needs a static password, not a rotating one.

Comment: That's what I was wondering. I guess it would require the decryption key to be stored on a chip like a TPM

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: I was asking if Filevault would be secure when using a Yubikey to login, which was answered by schroeder (it's not secure)

Comment: I don't think schroeder answered with "it's not secure" but just "you can't use them together"

Answer (score -1):

Seems like Filevault can't be secured with a Yubikey when using a dynamic password since it doesn't have a TPM that can securely store cryptographic keys (which was expected)